# How to speed up loading of large plain text files in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I was evaluating Sublime Text 3 against SciTE and tested in both text editors loading of very large (>200 MByte) plain text files having a custom extension (`.MD5idx`).

Sublime Text 3 needs much more time (several seconds more then SciTE) before the opened file shows up and I suppose it is because Sublime does some pre-evaluation of the file content like e.g. detecting areas suitable for folding (there are fold triangles available depending on indentation of non-white characters in the file).

I have searched the Internet and the docs but can't find how to switch the pre-evaluation of plain text files during loading them for display what is probably what slows Sublime down compared to SciTE.

All of the following settings:

```
"fold_buttons": false,
"word_wrap": false,
"auto_match_enabled": false,
```

doesn't have an impact on speed of displaying the content of large plain text files.

> Any hints how to speed up loading of large plain files in Sublime?

---

---

**UPDATE 2017-05-18**: Excerpt from what you can read on the [sublime-forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-performance-with-very-large-files/9832/12) (link provided by `Keith Hall` in the comment, title of discussion: `Sublime Text performance with very large files`)

Status as of Nov. 2016:

> "**The best solution would be to rework the editing or rendering core somewhat as my suspicion is that the issues lie there** but in the absence of that, progress bars, warnings and opportunities to cancel anything that's taking too long would be a definite plus.
>   I wonder, is there any chance that this will get some attention? **It's really frustrating!!**"

what seem to confirm my observation that Sublime has a problem with performance in case of large files and gives a hint towards the conclusion that **there is no solution to this problem available**.

> **It seems that if you want to work with very large files SciTE based on Scintilla is currently the better choice.**

Comment: [you could try disabling word wrap](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-performance-with-very-large-files/9832/10?u=kingkeith)

Comment: @KeithHall a good idea to disable word wrap, but it doesn't help (see updated question - disabling auto-match doesn't help either).